# MSVC 2022: Not working: #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022

In MSVC 2019, the following worked to set the linker's subsystem:

`#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")`

I upgraded to MSVC 2022 and this no longer works for me. Was that functionality removed?

Comment: *and this no longer works for me* -- What do you mean by "no longer works"?  What determined that it no longer works?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-170#linker), only the following comment-type linker options are allowed: `/DEFAULTLIB`, `/EXPORT`, `/INCLUDE`, `/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY`, `/MERGE`, `/SECTION`. Since `/SUBSYSTEM` is not listed, this is probably not a bug.

Comment: @heapunderrun: Interesting. I guess MS removed that functionality. That definetly used to work. See here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968857/c-win32-running-a-program-without-a-command-prompt-window/7968940#7968940